# How to debug Spring if project deployed from console to Tomcat server?

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, debugging, tomcat

I have issue to deploy Spring project directly from Eclipse. It doesn't work if I try run to server option from Eclipse. But same project works fine if I deploy from console to local Tomcat. I would like to debug it by setting break point and also want to see debug output to console as I used many log as logger.info("Listing Walks"); Where is this log if I deploy from console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the console in your tomcat folder do

```
set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
bin/catalina.bat jpda start
```

This starts tomcat in debug mode
Then in in eclipse you can create a remote debug profile to attach to the tomcat process on port 8000

Comment: you're welcome, please accept this answer if it solved your problem :)